# How can i return 2 rows in a where select?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

Here is the problem...I have these tables:

```
crs
title|semester
c++  |a
java |b
sql  |a

crsstu
regnum|title
11131 |java
11131 |c++
11132 |java
11132 |sql
11133 |c++
11133 |sql
```

what i want to do is select a registration number(regnum) from crsstu and table and i want to see in which courses he is not registered yet.
Example:if i select regnum 11131 then it has to return sql,or with 11132 it returns c++.

I've came up to this far:

```
select a.title 
from crs as a,crsstu as b
where b.registrationnumber != 11133 
and a.title != (select title 
                from crsstu 
                where registrationnumber = 11133)
```

but it shows me a 1242 error (Subquery returns more than 1 row).I know i am close to the answer but i dont know what more to do.Any answer would be helpfull.Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Just change `!=` to `NOT IN`.  IN and NOT IN allow comparison to a set of items.

```
select a.title 
from crs as a,crsstu as b
where b.registrationnumber != 11133 
and a.title NOT IN (select title 
                from crsstu 
                where registrationnumber = 11133)
```

Answer (score 2):

`NOT IN` is one of the possible solutions, but you are also over-complicating your query.
Should be just

```
SELECT title FROM crs
WHERE title NOT IN (SELECT title FROM crsstu WHERE regnum = 11131)
```

Can also be done with `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT a.title FROM crs a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM crsstu b WHERE a.Title = b.Title AND b.regnum = 11131)
```

or `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM crs a
LEFT JOIN crsstu b ON a.Title = b.Title AND b.regnum = 11131
WHERE b.regnum IS NULL
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41a32/9)**

Answer (score 0):

Use Join there will be better:

```
select title,regnum
from crs as a join crsstu as b
on a.title = b.title
where b.regnum != 11133
and a.title NOT IN (select title 
                from crsstu 
                where registrationnumber = 11133)
```